# Prevent specific @Entities to generate table - hibernate JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entity, named-query

**Is it possible to stop spring JPA from generating table for a specific entity ?**

**Reason:**
I want to put all my native sql queries into a separate object using @NamedNativeQuery. But @NameNativeQuery requires @Entity annotation. Due to that, and unwanted table is generated automatically.
Is it possible to add an @Entity, and stop at the same time spring boot to generate table for that entity ?

P.S: I don't want to put the queries into the parent @entity, because there are too many queries. I want to have a good model structure.

My settings :

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Spring Boot version : 2.3.3
Hibernate version : 5.6.7.Final
```

Comment: Have you looked at adding/defining an orm.xml file for your named queries?

Comment: Hi @Chris, yes just looked at it. Thanks for the advice. Thus, I would like to have more control over the SQL request. If I add it in xml, I am not informed about changes which are done in tables, like if a column was removed etc. My query requests are pretty complex. Is there any similar alternatives ?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your concern or the difference. I’m suggesting you put your queries into orm.xml. If a column is removed, there is no difference from having them defined in annotations vs in an entity- the queries are parsed and validated by a JPA provider on deployment and can mix and match annotations with xml. Is there some tool you are using that isn’t finding or using the orm.xml for validation?

Comment: Hey @Chris, yes this will work. Thanks a lot. I was using <named-query> instead of <named-native-query> , that's why it was not validating properly.

Comment: Native queries are raw sql, and I don't think can be validated unless executed, while named queries (JPQL) are validated against the entity model. Most IDEs can validate JPQL queries, and you can even run your JPA implementation in a way it can validate your persistence unit for you in build/compile time tools without requiring a database setup. If I'm wrong, I'm happy to be educated on how you are getting the native SQL query validated.